# Delphi Comport Carriage Return and Line Feed

Tags: string, delphi

I've designed a little project reads from Comport with ComPort Library version 4.10. When i tested with com0com emulator it works perfectly but when i read data from real machine (it's an electronic test machine sending data via RS232) data comes with CR and LF,i've searched alot and tried all procedures to clear CR&LF but failed.

Here are my codes;

```
var veri:string;
begin
panel1.Color:=clGreen;
panel1.Caption:='VERİ OKUNUYOR';
veri:=Trim(Str);
memo1.lines.add(CleanupString(trim(veri)));
```

I've tried to remove #13,#13#10,#13+#10,#32,sLineBreak and tried below functions;

```
function CleanupString(S :string) :string;
var
  i :integer;
begin
  Result := S;
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
    if Result[i] in [#3..#13] then
      Result[i] := '_';
end;
function RemoveCRLF (const aString : string) : string;
     var  i, j : integer; 
     begin 
     result := aString; 
     j := 0; 
     for i := 1 to Length (result) do 
          begin 
          if (not (result [i] in [#10, #13])) 
          then begin 
               inc (j); 
               result [j] := result [i]; 
               end; 
          end; 
     SetLength (result, j); 
     end;
```

But no luck so far, below image shows what my memo content looks like;
[image]
Device sending data starting with "APSiS0BE" and seems like sending CR&LF with every parameter but i couldn't be able to get data in one line.

Comment: Please show how do you receive and store data. And what Delphi version is used? Are you aware about Ansi/Unicode stuff?

Comment: @MBo receiving data with ComDataPacket via Onpacket event,i'm using Delphi 7 and i'm not familiar with Ansi/Unicode stuff, due to low reputation i'm not able to edit my question.

Comment: Everything you do to remove `CRLF` goes down the drain when you use `Add` to add lines to the `Memo`. Take once more a look at J...'s answer. If you need to add text as is to the `Memo` use the `Text` property: `Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + veri;`

Comment: Where do you store received data? What is a source for data shown at your picture?

Comment: @TomBrunberg appending to the `Text` property is very inefficient. It has to retrieve the current text into a new allocated `String`, then reallocate that `String` to append the new text, and then finally clear the entire Memo and re-parse the new `String` ftom scratch. That overhead adds up over time as the `Text` grows. It is much faster and less overhead to move the caret to the end of the Memo using the `SelStart` property and then insert the new text using the `SelText` property. No retrieval, no reallocation, no re-parsing

Comment: @Remy I'm fully aware of the inefficiency in concatenating memo contents as I suggested. The purpose of my  suggestion was however only to demonstrate that the CRLF's, that OP tries to get rid of (if they even occur in the communication), are coming back as a consequence of using the `Add()` method, and that OP can see the CRLF's disappear if he instead uses the text concatenation. OTOH, OP seems to have nothing more to comment on the issue, so I really don't know if he has understood what two answers and my comment are saying, or if there's some other problems too.

Comment: @TomBrunberg i understand your suggestions and solutions but i'm out of the office now,in couple hours i'll test and will let you know.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks for your patience and kindless help, you were right about memo1.lines.add is the wrong approach and memo1.text:=memo1.text+veri has solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: by the way why did i get -1 for my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you are seeing what you believe you are seeing.

When you add a line to TMemo, you implicitly add a CR+LF, so you are removing them, but then adding them back in. If you were not, when you open the contents in Notepad++ as you do, there would be empty blank lines, and you are not seeing them.

So, I think you are successfully removing the CR+LF, you just don't realise it.

Comment: thanks for heads up,you were right i was clearing from stream but adding again those CR+LF with memo1.lines.add command. now i'm using memo1.text:=memo1.text+veri as Tom Brunberg mentioned and everything works fine. Thanks alot.

Comment: It is weird idea to store data in visual control! Collect data in AnsiString. Use Memo only for debugging purposes, showing some last data pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi has the [`Trim`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Trim) method which is built in and will remove leading and trailing whitespace and control characters (CRLF, etc).  Your method removes them from anywhere in the string but for RS-232 protocols often `Trim` is all you would typically need.

That said, the `TMemo.lines.Add` method adds a line to the memo... with a CRLF, so if you're examining the memo output it will naturally have line ending characters in it.  Without it the text would just continue on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I use ComPort too and I use StringReplace to remove CR + LF :

```
S:= StringReplace(C, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

[StringReplace](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace)

Comment: I've allready tried stringreplace with "#13,#13#10,#13+#10,#32,sLineBreak" but no luck.